# NAudio Record buffer full after 5 seconds of recording

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm making a program using Visual C# Studio that records from a microphone.

I wish to record for a few minutes, but when I try to record, it shows me an error with 'Buffer Full' after it records for 5 seconds.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Play Button
{
  fileName = "lastReplay.wav";            

  FileStream FS_Write = File.OpenWrite("lastReplay.wav");
  FS_Write.Close();

  int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

  sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
  sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
  sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100,  
      NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

  NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new
      NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

  sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>
      (sourceStream_DataAvailable);
  waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(fileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);
  sourceStream.StartRecording();
}


private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
{
  if (waveWriter == null) return;
  waveWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
  waveWriter.Flush();
}
```

Does anyone knows what is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: can you try to leave out the `waveWriter.Flush();`?

Comment: InvalidOperationException (Buffer Full)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of code in there you don't need. Get rid of creating the empty WAV file. Also, there is no need for the `WaveInProvider`. In fact, that is what is causing the buffer full exception, since nothing is reading from it.

Comment: Wow! problem solved!
Thanks Mark! 
Can I have your facebook? I still have a lot of problems regarding NAudio, wish to know more about it from you. :)

Comment: best place for questions about NAudio is on the discussion forums at naudio.codeplex.com